# How to know how many pixels were scrolled in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that contains different child views.

Then user scrolls it.

I want to know exactly how many pixels user scrolled in comparison with the beginning state.

In other words, I want to know exactly the distance (in pixels) from current content of screen and the first item of `RecyclerView`.

I see `RecyclerView` has a method `computeVerticalScrollOffset`. But that method returns wrong value.

Comment: @pskink `OnScrollListener` only gives `dx` and `dy` value for everytime user scrolls. But what I want is the total distance between current content on screen and the first item of `RecyclerView`

Comment: @pskink I did it. But it takes me to another problem: if we programatically scroll `RecyclerView` by calling the method `scrollTo()`, we have no deltas and cannot update the total distance. So the total distance doesn't work any more

Comment: @pskink How? If I know how to update it correctly, I did not ask this question

Comment: @pskink Does it matter? For some reasons I have to call `scrollTo`. But the main question is: how to know exactly the distance from current content of screen to the beginning of `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `OnScrollListener`. Override `onScroll()` method, and its arguments are the distance scrolled by horizontal or vertical axis.

But there are few problems. This passes not the final scroll value, but many values, u have to summarize until the state becomes `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`.

```
private class YourOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

        private int scrollXDistance = 0;
        private int scrollYDistance = 0;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "X distance: " + scrollXDistance + " " + "Y distance:" + scrollYDistance);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            scrollXDistance += dx;
            scrollYDistance += dy;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if we programatically scroll `RecyclerView` by calling the method `scrollTo()`, we have no `dx` and `dy` and cannot update the total distance. So the total distance doesn't work any more